# How does struts 1.X ActionForm handle pure html checkbox list?

Tags: checkbox, struts, actionform

I am dealing with an old application which uses struts 1.2. And for some reason, we are using pure html form to submit to struts action. For example:

for the content output of testAction.do, I try to submit to itself.

item 1
 item 2

Then I associate an form bean TestForm with testAction.

I am not sure how to specify the properties in the form so that it take the value from myitem1 after user click "submit"

I tried to add
getMyitem1(), setMyitem1(String[] items), getSelectedMyitem1(), setSelectedMyitem1(String[] items)

Those set methods are only called when page are loaded.

I guess my understanding of ActionForm in struts 1.x must be wrong.

Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, let's clarify a bit how Struts manages form submits:

- you submit some values using a HTML form to an action (in this case the action is a Struts action, usually *.do);
- Struts receives the requests because of the ActionServlet (specified in web.xml);
- based on the information you specified in your struts-config.xml file, a specific Action class is selected (the one matching your request);
- based on the identified Action an action form is obtained (again based on the info you specify in struts-config.xml);
- an instance of this ActionForm is created or recycled (based on the scope of the form: request vs session);
- **data from the request is binded to the form properties**;
- your action execute(...) method is called with this form object.

Now, binding is done based on name; **name of the request parameter matching the name of the property in the form**. The name of the request parameter is off course the name of an input field from the HTML form you submitted.

For example, if you submit an input with name `test`, you should have the following accessors in your action form class (which respect JavaBeans convention for property named `test`):

```
public void setTest(String val) { ... }
public String getTest() { ... }
```

If you have a list of values attached to the `test` parameter (which I assume is your case since you mention a check box list) the accessors change to array type:

```
public void setTest(String[] val) { ... }
public String[] getTest() { ... }
```

But again **the name is used for matching**, always the name.

Not sure what you are trying to do with item 1 item 2. Are these the values that are submitted for your input (equivalent of `test`)?

Comment: The step is my assumption too, but seems when submit, the setTest in the form next got called. It is only called when page is loading...

Comment: Are you sure that the values are sent under the correct name? Can you intercept the request (or debug at server) and see what is submitted? Could something interfere, a javascript maybe?

Comment: Just found the problem, the variable case was wrong. Thanks for helping.